# Android. Не работает GET запрос через протокол http, притом через https работает

Tags: java, android, http, get, https

Есть два сайта - один использует протокол https, другой http. На них загружен один и тот же файл api.php. (да и вообще оба сайта являются копией друг друга). Сайты выглядят так:

1. https://www.site.000webhost.com/
2. http://site.online/

Сам запрос соответственно:

1. https://www.site.000webhost.com/api.php?connect=check
2. http://site.online/api.php?connect=check

Должен придти ответ: server_connect.

Если делать запрос через браузерную строку, то все нормально приходит в обоих случаях. Но вот если делать запрос через приложение, то в первом случае (https...) все проходит нормально, а вот во втором приложение вылетает, когда делает этот же самый запрос.

Исходники:

Класс для GET запроса:

```
class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... path) {
        String content;
        try {
            content = getContent(path[0]);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            content = ex.getMessage();
        }
        return content;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String content) { //метод для получения ответа
        if (content.equals("server_connect")){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainCl.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.server_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btn.setText(R.string.next);
        btn.setEnabled(true);
    }

    private String getContent(String path) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(path);
            HttpsURLConnection c = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setReadTimeout(PublicVar.time);
            c.connect();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buf.append(line);
            }
            return (buf.toString());
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Сам GET-запрос:

```
new ProgressTask().execute((PublicVar.URL + "server_connect=" + "VersionApp: "
            + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME + ";_SDK:_"+ Integer.toString(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) + ";_ModelPhone:_" + android.os.Build.MODEL.toString()).replaceAll(" ", "_"));
```

Переменная в классе `PublicVar`:

```
static final String URL = "https://www.site.000webhost.com/api.php?"; //(работает)
```

или

```
static final String URL = "http://www.site.online/api.php?"; //(не работает)
```

Comment: `HttpsURLConnection c = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();` может быть поэтому? Для `http` нужно использовать `HttpURLConnection`

Comment: да, именно поэтому... Спасибо.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Вся проблема в том, что я использовал:

```
HttpsURLConnection c = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

А для Http нужно использовать:

```
HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```